# Which popular synthesizer voices are available for software?

Tags: synthesizer

Since the 1970s, there have been tens of thousands of synthesizer sounds, hundreds of which have become so popular that they are instantly recognizable, as well as dozens of synthesizer "models" (not sure what the correct term is) such "XG" or "AWM2".

Which of these are available in commercial or open-source software packages or modules such as VSTs?

Comment: That's going to be an awfully long list :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

- Reason software (many vintage, classic synths emulated)
- Korg Legacy software (many of their own synths emulated)

Not sure about the VST side of the above, there may be support but I would invite you to research this further.

Comment: Pretty much **all** the most popular classics are there in VST too.